# Swift IndexingGenerator only works when assigned to a var

Tags: swift

Working through the Advanced Swift book in a playground (Xcode 7b 5), and am seeing this:

```
var a1 = [1,2,3]  
var a1gen = a1.generate()  
a1gen.next()  
// => 1

// but:  
a1.generate().next()  
// => value of type 'IndexingGenerator<[Int]>' has no member 'next'
```

Why? I think it's because a1gen needs to be a reference type, not sure why you have to store the reference type to access it though.  Could it be an evaluation order issue? I tried:

```
(a1.generate()).next()
```

but still get the same error

Comment: Thanks, couldn't figure out how to find the answered question. Not sure how to close it as a dup or if I can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the variable `a1gen` is declared with `var` — it is mutable. And `next()` is a mutating function. It needs something stable to mutate - a mutable *reference*. The loose `a1.generate()` in `a1.generate().next()` is not such a thing.

It's really no different from the fact that this is legal:

```
var d = [String:String]()
d["hey"] = "ho"
```

but this is not:

```
[String:String]()["hey"] = "ho"
```

Or that this is legal:

```
var i = 1
i++
```

but this is not:

```
1++
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, not sure if I can select your answer or not since this was already answered in a previous question.

Answer (score 0):

An `IndexingGenerator` is not a `Collection`.

[EDIT] Maybe I wasn't being clear enough. You can call next for a `GeneratorType`, but calling `generate` on a `GeneratorType` *is not a good idea*, because it doesn't make sense for a `GeneratorType` to be able to `generate` itself: after all, it's no `Collection`, it's a `GeneratorType`. Thus, it's immutable.

Comment: I understand the immutability, but still unclear how
     `a1.generate()` 
which is a GeneratorType is different in type than the same thing stuffed into a var, in a type sense.  I get that I a generator must be a reference type so must be mutable.  Perhaps its just the error that's misleading.